# Difference of hypotheses between weak and strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability, statistics, law-of-large-numbers

I have read several questions on the difference between weak and strong laws in terms of convergence in probability vs convergence a.s. and I think I grasp them.

However, I have uncertainty on the hypotheses. Is the following claim true ?

> For i.i.d. samples from a random variable with finite mean, both strong and weak laws apply ?

My trouble comes from the [Wikipedia explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) where a small line at the end of the "weak law" section states:

> There are also examples of the weak law applying even though the expected value does not exist.

and indeed, in the section "difference between weak and strong law", the examples are all mentioning "no expected value".

What troubles me is that the weak law, as far as I know, is stated as:

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \quad \lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} P(|\bar{X}-\mu| > \epsilon) =0$$

right ?

Well, then, what does this law become if, as examples mentioned above claim, expected value does not exist ? What's $\mu$ then ? The Wikipedia article refers to "conditional convergence", but what does that mean ?

So, to sum up and facilitate the answers, I have two questions:

(i): Is the claim "For i.i.d. samples from a random variable with finite mean, both strong and weak laws apply." true ? (If not, precise which additional hypothesis for the strong law to hold in some cases)

(ii): What does the weak law look like when "the expected value does not exist", which does not seem very easily "inferable" for me when looking at the standard definition despite the fact that Wikipedia mentions several "examples" showing that strong law does not hold in these cases, but only the weak law ?

Comment: Regarding (i): Yes!

Comment: @PhoemueX and regarding (ii) ? ^^

Comment: In (ii), $\mu$ is the value to which you get convergence in probability (but not almost surely).  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/609954/2958 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/205564/2958 illustrate a couple of the Wikipedia examples by simulation.  One of those has $\mathbb P\left(X_i=\frac{(-2)^n}{n} \right)=\frac1{2^n}$ for positive integer $n$, where trying to find $\mathbb E[X_i]$ might suggest looking at $\sum\limits_n \frac{(-2)^n}{n} \frac1{2^n}$ but that sum only conditionally converges to $-\log_e(2)$.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the references, but how do you define "conditional convergence" exactly ? And also, are these examples really within the scope of law of large numbers or "just" illustrate the difference between kinds of convergence ?

Comment: [Conditional convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence) here indicates that the partial sums converge but that the partial sums of the absolute values do not.  In the  $\mathbb P\left(X_i=\frac{(-2)^n}{n} \right)=\frac1{2^n}$ you get the sample average converging to $-\log_e(2)$ in probability so you can say that in that sense WLLN applies, but the sample average does not converge almost surely to anything so you can say that in that sense SLLN does not apply.  [The simulations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/609954/2958) attempt to illustrate this.

Comment: @Henry Things start to become clearer for me now, thanks. By the way, I did not know that conditional convergence was referring to the concept it actually is (though I know the concept itself of course), there isn't even a Wikipedia page in French, my mother tongue, that's maybe why :)

Comment: @MysteryGuy [Apparently](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_absolue#S%C3%A9rie_num%C3%A9rique_absolument_convergente) the term in French is *semi-convergente*